# HDFS file was overwrited when using Spark Streaming,but I don't want this

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, flume

In my Spark Streaming application,as follow:

```
val lines=FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc,"hdp2.domain",22222,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)

val words = lines.filter(examtep(_))
words.foreachRDD(exam(_))

//some other code

 def exam(rdd:RDD[SparkFlumeEvent]):Unit={
    if(rdd.count()>0) {
      println("****Something*****")
      val newrdd=rdd.map(sfe=>{
      val tmp=new String(sfe.event.getBody.array())
      tmp
      })
    newrdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/spark/appoutput/Temperaturetest")
    }
}
```

When I run this application,in the method `words.foreachRDD()`,every time the `exam()` method execute, `newsrdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/...")` will execute,and the file in dir Temperaturetest will be overwriteed, in the end, I can't get the complete data.
What should I do to write all the data in `foreacheRDD()` to HDFS??
In additional,my spark version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Use directly [DStream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream) functions instead of RDD functions after create Flume stream. Dstream has built-in saveAsTextFiles action that does what you look for.

```
lines.filter( line =>  //Do your filter )
.map( spf => spf.event.getBody)
.saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/output")
```

Comment: Thank you for answer my question.I did as above,but I get many HDFS files which is empty,don't have any data I want.If I use 'spf=>new String(spf.event.getBody.array)',I can get the data,but there are also many other empty files in HDFS,but I only want the files contains data.Do you know what should I do?

Comment: Do you refer .CRC or .SUCCESS files? If these are empty is totally normal.  Do you have part-XXXXX files empty?

Comment: Sorry,I did a test again.use 'spf=>spf.event.getBody',also can get some data,but it's like 'B@7afeed0b' etc,it's not the text.'spf=>spf.event.getBody' and 'spf=>new String(spf.event.getBody.array)' ，either will get the data,but only the second one get normal text data.However,both of them will generate som dir "/user/spark/appoutput/Temperaturetest-XXXXX" in which the part-XXXXX files are empty。Now, I don't want these non-data dir,because it's streaming application,after a long time,there will be a large number of non-data dir with empty part-XXXX file

Comment: I changed my codes like this:`val errliness=lines.filter(examtep(_)).map(sfp=>new String(sfp.event.getBody.array)) errliness.foreachRDD(rdd=>{ if(rdd.count()>0){ println("***********something***") errliness.saveAsTextFiles("/user/spark/appoutput/Temperaturetest") }`  but it still have many empty dir and files.Do you have any suggestion？

Comment: Empty files can be because some partitions have no data, try a repartition after create flume stream.

Comment: e......,probablely I didn't describe well.It's not the problem of partition.Because I use a `filter` methed,so some `errliness`(in my application,most of the `errliness` have no data) have no data ,but after `saveAsTextFiles` method, it still generate a dir `Temperaturetest-XXXXXXX` in HDFS,in the dir, there is only a empty `part-00000` file,I don't need this non-data dir generated by empty `DStream`, this is what actually troubles me now